# Google Scripts function for CopyPaste loop not working

Tags: vba, google-apps-script

I want to create a Script for a Spreadsheet that copies and pastes some values in a loop until a cell returns "Yes".
This is the code I have, but it is not working

```
function CopyPaste() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var check = spreadsheet.getRange("Hypothesis!C4");
  var source = spreadsheet.getRange("Macro!E6:AQ8");
  var destination = spreadsheet.getRange("Macro!E12:AQ14");

while(check!= "Yes"){
  source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
 }
}
```

This is the code that is working on VBA but I can´t implement on Google Scripts.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Do While Worksheets("Hypothesis").Range("C7") <> "Yes"
   Worksheets("Macro").Range("E6:AR8").Copy
   Worksheets("Macro").Range("E12:AR14").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Loop

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You going to have to check the value of check inside the loop or it will continue to go forever.

Answer (score 0):

The `check` variable you are using is returning a `Range` object and **not a value**. In order to retrieve the value corresponding to the `Hypothesis!C4` you will have to use the `getValue()` method:

```
var check = spreadsheet.getRange("Hypothesis!C4").getValue();
```

Moreover, in the current stage, your `while` loop is an infinite one since the condition will always return true (if `check` is different than "Yes"). Taking this into account, you should adjust your while condition such that it performs a correct looping by adding an `if` condition inside the loop or adjusting the current one such that the `check` variable *will return* "Yes".

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue).